# Query posts with post_excerpt exists

Tags: wordpress

Looking forward to showing only posts that have excerpt set by user.

Checked `WP_Query` documentation but found nothing relevant. Also searched for questions here on SO.

We want to give more control to authors to let them handpick posts displayed by whether or not excerpt has been set.

Last resort will to to use WPDB or modify WP_Query SQL query, but would be nice to know if there's a nicer way...

Comment: The second answer in this WordPress thread may contain the query you're after. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256592/return-only-posts-which-have-post-excerpt. Failing that, in the loop you can use: if ( has_excerpt( $post->ID ) ) {

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the query.
Just check there are excerpt for that post or not inside the wp loop.
To check that you can use this function

```
has_excerpt(get_the_ID())
```

Your code should be

```
if(has_excerpt(get_the_ID())){
//front end executable code.
}
```

Try the code then let me know the result.
Thanks